# Match all strings containing a string followed by a dot followed by exactly two letters in Vim?

Tags: vim

For example, we have a file with all kind of domain names about 800 lines.
we would like to using vim to quickly find all the domain names that start www.example.**
where ** is 2 letters for any kind.

```
example.site"
example.link]"
example.example'
example.ex'
example.xx]"'
```

Now we can search in vim with term `example.`, but how can we wildcard to match, so we can find     `example.ex' and example.xx]"` in our example above ?

we don't want to highlight string like

```
> example.site" 
> example.link]" 
> example.example'
```

just `example.ex and example.xx`
(it would be better if we can delete all others and leave the only matched string)

Comment: you can use `:/example.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]/`  I suppose any of regexp can just work fine

Comment: Yes. You are right. I actually need to improve my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
/example\.\w\w\W
```

To search for 'example.' followed by two 'word characters' `\w` and then by a
'non-word character' `\W`

To delete all lines not matching the pattern you can do:

```
:v/example\.\w\w\W/delete
```

Or just:

```
:v/example\.\w\w\W/d
```

Or using the g[lobal] command with negation `!`:

```
:g!/example\.\w\w\W/d
```

The 3 above commands all will turn this:

```
example.site"
example.link]"
example.example'
example.ex'
example.xx]"'
```

into this:

```
example.ex'
example.xx]"'
```

#### Update

For dealing with cases where these patterns are on the same line like this:

```
example.site"
example.example' example.ex' example.link]"
example.xx]"'
```

You can use a search pattern like this:

```
/example\.\w\w\w[^ ]* \?
```

The way this works is to find 'example.' followed by three 'word characters'
followed by any number of characters which are *not* spaces `[^ ]*` and ending
with an optional space  `\?`.

You can therefore replace the matches with nothing (the `g` means apply this
substitution for every match on the line, not just the first one it finds):

```
:%s/example\.\w\w\w[^ ]* \?//g
```

to get:

```
example.ex' 
example.xx]"'
```

(and you could also remove blank lines with `:g/^$/d`. In fact, you could chain
this together using the `|` and do it all in one with `:%s/example\.\w\w\w[^ ]* \?//g | %g/^$/d`)

Comment: Thank you. so it only highlight the desired result. (not sure why, maybe I have different vim config file or on a mac).

Comment: I know why now. Those desired strings not are actually in a separated lines.  since there are some in the same lines. like  example.example' example.ex' example.xx]"' example.ex' example.xx]"' are all in one line. But it helps a lot alreay. Thank you.

Comment: @Maxfield I updated the answer to cover the case of multiple patterns on the same lines.